# How to fix this Value Error | ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2048,2050) into shape (2048) | line 10 and 16

Tags: python, audio, valueerror, mfcc

```
def frame_audio(audio, FFT_size=2048, hop_size=10, sample_rate=44100):
# hop_size in ms

audio = np.pad(audio, int(FFT_size / 2), mode='reflect')
frame_len = np.round(sample_rate * hop_size / 1000).astype(int)
frame_num = int((len(audio) - FFT_size) / frame_len) + 1
frames = np.zeros((frame_num,FFT_size))

for n in range(frame_num):
    frames[n] = audio[n*frame_len:n*frame_len+FFT_size]

return frames
```

hop_size = 15 #ms
FFT_size = 2048

audio_framed = frame_audio(audio, FFT_size=FFT_size, hop_size=hop_size, sample_rate=sample_rate)
print("Framed audio shape: {0}".format(audio_framed.shape))

Comment: don't post your traceback as a title. post it in your question in plain text

Comment: you should use `reshape` and avoid the for loop: `audio.reshape((frame_num, FFT_size))`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.